# unicode argument expected, got 'str'

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

I'm using python 2.7.12. Running `pd.__version__` returns u'0.19.0'.

I'm using a module called dalmatian. For one of the functions, once I run verbatim what is provided in the documentation, I get the error:

`wm.update_participant_set('all_participants', participant_df.index)`
`TypeError: unicode argument expected, got 'str'`

I have an inkling suspicion that this might be due to the version of pandas or python that I'm using. Running `participant_df.index` returns:

```
Index([u'100_2', u'101_3', u'102_2', u'103_3', u'104_2', u'105_2', u'106_4',
   u'107_4', u'108_4', u'109_1',
   ...
   u'91_2', u'92_3', u'93_2', u'94_4', u'95_4', u'96_3', u'97_2', u'98_3',
   u'99_1', u'9_1'],
  dtype='object', name=u'participant_id', length=523)`
```

I've also tried submitting this as `.astype(unicode)` and as `.index.values`. I suppose I don't really know how to troubleshoot this further. Any thoughts?

**EDIT TO INCLUDE TRACEBACK**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/gpfs/fs1/home/jrouhana/jrouhana/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dalmatian/wmanager.py", line 1045, in update_participant_set
    self.update_entity_set('participant', participant_set_id, participant_ids)
  File "/gpfs/fs1/home/jrouhana/jrouhana/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dalmatian/wmanager.py", line 1030, in update_entity_set
    self.upload_entities('{}_set'.format(etype), set_df, index=False)
  File "/gpfs/fs1/home/jrouhana/jrouhana/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dalmatian/wmanager.py", line 164, in upload_entities
    df.to_csv(buf, sep='\t', index=index)
  File "/modules/EasyBuild/software/pandas/0.19.0-foss-2016b-Python-2.7.12/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.19.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1381, in to_csv
    formatter.save()
  File "/modules/EasyBuild/software/pandas/0.19.0-foss-2016b-Python-2.7.12/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.19.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/formats/format.py", line 1475, in save
    self._save()
  File "/modules/EasyBuild/software/pandas/0.19.0-foss-2016b-Python-2.7.12/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.19.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/formats/format.py", line 1562, in _save
    self._save_header()
  File "/modules/EasyBuild/software/pandas/0.19.0-foss-2016b-Python-2.7.12/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.19.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/formats/format.py", line 1530, in _save_header
    writer.writerow(encoded_labels)
TypeError: unicode argument expected, got 'str'
```

Comment: Do you have the full stack trace of the error?

Comment: I made an edit to add the traceback.

Comment: Not sure what the issue is, but note, `'all_participants'` is a string not a unicode. Really, you should just use Python 3

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm aware. I tried turning `all_participants` to unicode before running. It's not the issue either. 

I'll take a look if all the packages I need are available in Python 3.

Comment: Kind of a late update, but changing over to Python3 resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I facced same error, the code was written in `python 3`, but i was running it with `python 2`.
so swiching to `python 3` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following at the beginning of the file:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```